# Turn iPhone into Dumb USB drive

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, iphone

I am looking to turn my iPhone into a standard USB drive that will work with any device that accepts USB (for instance plugging into a TV). I do not mind completely killing the iOS firmware on it (I would in fact prefer that) but I can not do anything on the device itself since the screen and power button are broken (my reason for wanting to do this in the first place). I am using a Mountain Lion Mac.

Thanks :)

Comment: Without the firmware it will be a brick...

Comment: Should have bought an Android to break. It has support for USB mass storage natively. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is going to be possible given your situation. There are apps, both jailbroken and not that might allow you to use your iPhone as a USB drive, but without being able to do anything on the iPhone itself, you're kind of out of luck.

[A few Mac/PC apps to explore the iPhone filesystem](http://lifehacker.com/5914638/the-best-desktop-file-explorer-for-iphone)

[A few iOS apps (some require jailbreak)](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-to-turn-your-iphone-into-an-external-hard-disk/)